# Defining a new section-like macro with hyperref bookmarks?

Tags: hyperref

I'm defining a macro for paragraph headers to separate out distinct sections in a letter (the usual \section command makes the header too big and bulky). I want to have hyperref generate bookmarks for each of these, as it does with things like \section. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The [`hyperref` manual](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) mentions the `\pdfbookmark[level]{text}{name}` macro. Still, if you need to typeset sections headers, the `\section` macro is what you want. You can redefine it to be smaller if needed. What document class are you using?

Comment: Thanks! I added a \pdfbookmark into the macro so it automatically sets bookmarks. I'm using revtex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use option `bookmarksdepth`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=paragraph]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Here is a paragraph} It isn't very long.

\paragraph{And here is another one} Not long either.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works also with `\documentclass{revtex4-1}`.